# Display number of Div Elements based on dropdown-value

Tags: jquery

I have 4 Div elements, and a dropdown. If I select a dropdown option such as "2", DivElement2 is shown and all others are hidden.

I want to change this, so that when I select option "2", both DivElement1 and DivElement2 are shown. I have this script which I need to use, but it's not exactly working:

```
$(".DropdownClass").chosen({
    inherit_select_classes: true,
    disable_search: true
}).change(function (e, params) {
    if ($(this).attr('name') == 'Count') {
        $('.CommonAttribute').hide();
        $('.CommonAttribute:lt(' + $(this).val() + ')').show();
    }
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hk87V/2/)

Comment: What the crap is chosen.? without that your code is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/Hk87V/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `.slice()` them like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/Hk87V/8/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  var catchDome = $("div.CommonAttribute");
 catchDome.hide();
 catchDome.eq(0).show();
 $(".DropdownClass").change(function () {
     catchDome.hide();
     catchDome.eq(this.value - 1).show();

 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hk87V/10/)

Or You want to show how many elements based on option selection

```
$(".DropdownClass").change(function () {

    $('.CommonAttribute').hide();
    $('.CommonAttribute:lt(' + this.value + ')').show();

});
```

### [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hk87V/17/)

Answer (score 0):

When you include in yout code choosen.js and css it works perfectly. Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hk87V/9/) and the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
      <script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.css">
  <style type='text/css'>
  </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(".DropdownClass").chosen().change(function (e, params) {
    if ($(this).attr('name') == 'Count') {
        $('.CommonAttribute').hide();
        $('.CommonAttribute:lt(' + $(this).val() + ')').show();
    }
});
});//]]>      
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <select class="DropdownClass" name="Count" id="selectModelNumber">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div class="CommonAttribute DivElement1">Div1</div>
<div class="CommonAttribute DivElement1">Div2</div>
<div class="CommonAttribute DivElement1">Div3</div>
<div class="CommonAttribute DivElement1">Div4</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$(".DropdownClass").change(function (e, params) {
    var count=parseInt($(this).val());
    $(".CommonAttribute").show();
    $(".CommonAttribute:gt("+(count-1)+")").hide();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hk87V/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Could you visit this fiddle link, you will get the result what do you expect.

```
$(".DropdownClass").chosen().change(function (e, params) {
if ($(this).attr('name') == 'Count') {
    $('.CommonAttribute').hide();
    $('.DivElement'+$(this).val()).show();
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hk87V/27/